# After removing elements with splice, there is undefined stuff

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I want to remove array elements by using `splice`

```
custom_boxes_exist.splice($.inArray(id, custom_boxes_exist),1);
custom_boxes_order.splice($.inArray(id, custom_boxes_order),1);
box_content.splice($.inArray(id, box_content),1);
```

When in output the array content after using splice I'm getting this output:

```
Array(5) [ "Content of box with id 0", undefined, undefined, undefined, "Content of box with id 4" ]
```

Somehow it's removing the elements and somehow it is not.

You can see it when you add a box, remove it and then add a new one

```js
var custom_box_id = 0;
var custom_boxes_order = [];
var custom_boxes_exist = [];
var box_content = [];


function addNewBox() {
  reOrderArray();
  custom_boxes_exist.push(custom_box_id);
  custom_boxes_order[custom_box_id] = 1;
  box_content[custom_box_id] = "Content of box with id " + custom_box_id;
  console.log("adding new box: with id " + custom_box_id);
  console.log(custom_boxes_order);
  console.log(custom_boxes_exist);
  console.log(box_content);
  $("#custom_boxes").prepend('<div id="box_' + custom_box_id + '" class="box">' + box_content[custom_box_id] + ' <span style="float:right;"><button onclick="changeOrder(' + custom_box_id + ',"up")">[UP]</button><button onclick="changeOrder(' + custom_box_id + ',"down")">[DOWN]</button><button onclick="deleteCustomBox(' + custom_box_id + ')">[x]</button></span></div>');
  custom_box_id++;
}

function changeOrder(id) {
  //
}

function reOrderArray() {
  $.each(custom_boxes_order, function(key, value) {
    custom_boxes_order[key] = value + 1;
  });
}

function testDel(id) {
  $.each(custom_boxes_exist, function(key, value) {
    if (value == id) {
      custom_boxes_exist.splice($.inArray(id, custom_boxes_exist), 1);
      return;
    }
  });
}

function deleteCustomBox(id) {
  $("#box_" + id).remove();
  custom_boxes_exist.splice($.inArray(id, custom_boxes_exist), 1);
  custom_boxes_order.splice($.inArray(id, custom_boxes_order), 1);
  box_content.splice($.inArray(id, box_content), 1);
}
```

```css
.box {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center><button onclick="addNewBox()">add new box</button></center>
<div id="editor_header" class="box">HEADER</div>
<div id="custom_boxes"></div>
<div id="editor_bottom" class="box">FOOTER</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] with sample data? You can [create a runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) by clicking the `[<>]` button in the editor.

Answer (score 2):

This is not because of `splice()`. It's because of the way you add to the arrays after you have removed elements. You do:

```
box_content[custom_box_id] = "Content of box with id "+custom_box_id;
```

`custom_box_id` increments every time you create a new box. If you create boxes `0`, `1`, and `2`, the array contains

```
box_content[0] = "Contents of box with id 0"
box_content[1] = "Contents of box with id 1"
box_content[2] = "Contents of box with id 2"
```

and `custom_box_id` is now `3`.

If you delete box 1, the array now contains:

```
box_content[0] = "Contents of box with id 0"
box_content[1] = "Contents of box with id 2"
```

Notice that the array indexes no longer match the IDs in the contents.

When you add the next box, you now have

```
box_content[0] = "Contents of box with id 0"
box_content[1] = "Contents of box with id 2"
box_content[3] = "Contents of box with id 3"
```

Notice that there's no `box_content[2]`, because `custom_box_id` was `3`. When you view the entire array, this missing element is shown as `undefined`.

If you don't want these gaps, you should use `push()` to add to the array rather than assigning to a specific index. You do this for the `custom_boxes_exist` array, but not `custom_boxes_order` and `box_contents`.